# how to handle shared event in VB.net class in C# form

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling

I have a WCF coded in VB.net who raises events. Those events are Shared. Look like this:

```
Shared Event onMissingSnapshots()
```

here's the call:

```
 Public Shared Sub FireMissingSnapshots()
    RaiseEvent onMissingSnapshots()
End Sub
```

which is called from the WCF callback Implements:

```
Private Class StatusCallback
    Implements ServiceReference.TravelSequenceCallback

    Public Sub onMissingSnapshots() Implements ServiceReference.TravelSequenceCallback.onMissingSnapshots
        cWCF_Moteur.FireMissingSnapshots()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I need to integrate this class in a C# WinForm project. Intellisense won't see the Shared event, so it gives error when I try to add a delegates handler. How can I implements those event in my C# project??

thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: why switching from vb.net to c#?

Comment: Shouldn't your shared event be public?

Comment: It needs to be a friend assembly for shared to work. Otherwise make it public

Answer (score 2):

Your event is poorly implemented, although I'm not 100% sure that that is the reason for your issue.  I just tried the following and it worked for me.  I created a DLL project in VB and added the following code:

```vb
Public Class Class1

    Public Shared Event MissingSnapshots As EventHandler

    Protected Shared Sub OnMissingSnapshots(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent MissingSnapshots(Nothing, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

That is the standard pattern for declaring and raising an event, except that you normally use `Me` rather than `Nothing` as the sender for instance events.  Also, as you can't override a `Shared` method, there's no point declaring the `OnMissingSnapshots` method `Overridable` and really no point declaring it `Protected` either.  This is probably the way to go:

```vb
Public Shared Event MissingSnapshots As EventHandler

Private Shared Sub OnMissingSnapshots(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent MissingSnapshots(Nothing, e)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub RaiseMissingSnapshots()
    OnMissingSnapshots(EventArgs.Empty)
End Su
```

I then added a C# WinForms application project to the same solution and referenced the VB project.  I was able to add the following code without issue, including with Intellisense:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1.MissingSnapshots += Class1_MissingSnapshots;
        }

        private void Class1_MissingSnapshots(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Standard pattern should probably supply the sender: `RaiseEvent MissingSnapshots(Me, e)`

Comment: @LarsTech, the event is `Shared` so there is no `Me`.  The `sender` is the **object** that raised the event.  In the case of a `Shared` event, there was no object that raised the event so `sender` would be `Nothing`.

Comment: Missed that.  I have never created a "shared" event.  Never saw a reason too.

Comment: @LarsTech, nor I.

Comment: thanks to your precious help, it works now! The class in VB has been referenced in vb projects for years and it worked perfectly. It's my first C# project, so my apologise if the question seems trivial or didn't made sense.

Comment: If raised from a `Shared` method or function, the event must also be `Shared`. | @LarsTech